# Setting of "tabindex" attribute in IE8 is not working using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
   <label for="radio_1">
        <input id="radio_1" type="radio" name="radio_group" />
        <span>Radio button 1</span>
    </label>

    <label for="radio_2">
        <input id="radio_2" type="radio" name="radio_group" >
        <span>Radio button 2</span>
    </label>

    <label for="radio_3">
        <input id="radio_3" type="radio" name="radio_group" />
        <span>Radio button 3</span>
    </label>
```

I want all the radio buttons above to have a `tabindex` attribute using `JQuery`. I tried the script below and it seems that it doesn't work. Do you have alternative for my problem? I also tried `.prop("tabindex", "1");` `.attr("tabindex", 1);` `.prop("tabindex", 1);` and all of these did not work.

```
$("input[name='radio_group']").attr("tabindex", "1");
```

Comment: you are setting the same `tabindex` to all the `input`s?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? IE8 support was dropped in 2.x.

Comment: Yes. I am adding all tabindex to all radio buttons.

Comment: I use jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.1